# Token number 2 (-d) not recognized. Command Result : 22 (Invalid argument) Fatal: Received unexpected end-of-file from server in Luna HSM

Tags: upgrade, updates, required, hsm

when I used this command pscp in Luna HSM I get this error: Token number 2 (-d) not recognized. Command Result : 22 (Invalid argument) Fatal: Received unexpected end-of-file from server in Luna HSM . I don't know.

Comment: I solved it when I request with wrong params

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I was a user on the Luna without the role privilege to use SCP.  The user had been created with a custom template and the scp privilege had been left off.