# Luna SA HSM - Syntax Error: Token number 1 (scp) not recognized. Command Result : 22 (Invalid argument)

Tags: hardware-security-module, safenet

I'm trying to setup NTLS from SafeNet Luna Client to Luna SA HSM. For that I need to scp the server certificate from the HSM to the Client machine.
When I run the command 'scp admin@:server.pem .', it throws the error:
Syntax Error: Token number 1 (scp) not recognized.
Command Result : 22 (Invalid argument)

Same error comes when I try to upload the client certificate to the HSM.

How to enable or install scp on HSM? Or what is an alternative way to upload the client certificate to the HSM other than scp?

Answer (score 0):

You should be running `scp` from your client OS.  Is it installed?  The Windows version of the Luna client also installs PuTTY for you, so that should be available in `Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient`.

Alternatively, from the Luna client utility (`lunacm`) simply run `clientconfig deploy -client <your client IP> -server <HSM IP> -partition <partition name>` adding `-hsmPassword <partition SO password>` if it's a password protected Luna HSM (otherwise you'll be prompted for the blue SO keys on a MFA Luna HSM). The command will prompt you for the HSM appliance administrator password. This command automates the `scp` of the certificates in both directions and adds the client to the partition authorisation list in one go.

https://thalesdocs.com/gphsm/luna/7/docs/network/Content/lunacm/commands/clientconfig/clientconfig_deploy.htm

Comment: Thank you Gareth for the response. 'scp' is available on the luna client system, but it seems it is either not available or admin account doesn't have the privileges to run it on the HSM. Hence running 'scp' fails with the given error. I tried running 'lunacm', but it gives the error: 'Failed to find any Luna HSMs!'. This is because it is unable to authenticate itself to the HSM.

Comment: The document mentions ' NOTE   If pscp or scp is blocked by a firewall, this command will fail and the certificates must be transferred by other secure means and registered manually. '.  I'm really interested in knowing what other means are available if 'scp' is not working.

Comment: `ssh` shouldn't be available on the HSM.  You use it to pull the server cert from the HSM and push your client auth cert to the HSM - all from the client.  Also, if you run `lunacm` without a HSM being configured then it naturally won't find a HSM.  You run `clientconfig` so that a Luna HSM is found.

Comment: Tried ./lunacm clientconfig deploy -server <hsm-hostname> -client <client-hostname> -par <partition-name> but it still gives the same error: Failed to find any Luna HSMs!

Comment: I found more info. This is an old HSM with software version Luna SA:4.5.0-12. It seems it doesn't support 'scp', but rather it has 'ctp' as the program to transfer files. 'ctp' stands for chrysalis transfer program. Unfortunately, I do not have it on my client system and cannot seem to find this utility anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Time for an upgrade?  Even Luna 5 & 6 are EOL!

Comment: Yeah, but that is something not possible right now, so somehow need a way to get the existing HSM working.

Comment: Shouldn't `ctp` be provided as part of the HSM client software?

Comment: The client software I've doesn't have the ctp. I'm unable to get hold of old client software that might have the ctp command.

Comment: You should be using the client software that relates to the version of HSM you have.  That version should have `ctp`.  If you use a later version (when the vendor moved to the `scp` protocol) then it's highly likely that it won't work.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a very old, unsupported HSM without the correct client software to operate it.  While you could approach Thales to see if they will supply the correct client, I wouldn't hold my breath.  Their support site only goes back to Luna 5 HSMs.  What exactly are you expecting from this community in terms of help?

Comment: Yes, the newer client doesn't seem to have ctp as the vendor moved to scp protocol. I was looking to see where I could get hold of ctp or an older client. I reached out to the community since there was a similar question raised earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760257/token-number-2-d-not-recognized-command-result-22-invalid-argument-fatal and thought if someone else had been in the same situation, perhaps they could provide some help or pointers.

Comment: But will the newer client work even if you did manage to exchange certs? I doubt it would, as early Luna HSM are extremely sensitive to software/firmware mismatches.

Comment: I don't know. Need to try and find out. But for that to happen, I should be able to setup the NTLs between the client and HSM.